# Is there a way to unmerge Google Sheets cells with gspread or some other Python library?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

`gspread` has [this](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=merge#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.merge_cells) method for merging cells but I don't find anything for unmerging. I see there's a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798539/google-sheets-unmerge-cells-and-fill-down) to do this in JavaScript, though, but my project is in Python so I would really like to stick to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you can achieve your goal using `batch_update` method of gspread. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```py
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) # Here, please use your script.
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
requests = [
    {
        "unmergeCells": {
            "range": {"sheetId": spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName).id}
        }
    }
]
spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

- In this sample script, all merged cells of "Sheet1" in a Spreadsheet are unmerged.
- When you want to unmerge the specific merged cells, please use the gridrange. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange)

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.
- This sample script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.0.0/api.html?highlight=batch_update#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [UnmergeCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#unmergecellsrequest)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! How have I not come across this?! I mean, I've seen `batch_update` but nothing came up when I searched for "batch_update unmerge"...

Comment: @m_ocean Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Unfortunately, it seemed that the method of unmerging cells is not included in the methods of gspread. So I proposed to use `batch_update` method. About `batch_update`, in the case of this, the request body is required to be created by checking the official document. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#unmergecellsrequest) Also, you can create and test the request body at ["Try this API"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).